# UIButton doesn't respond in my phone but simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uibutton

When I run my project using simulator the button responds to and returns data but when I use my iPhone I see the button's alpha changing but it returns nil!

I'm using HTTP request and the button is on view. 
it's the signup button

[image]

[image]

**Edit** 
my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var signup: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    signup.alpha   = 1;
   }

func loginButton(_ enabled: Bool) -> () {
    func enable(){
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: {
            self.signup.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHex("#33CC00", alpha: 1)
        }, completion: nil)
        signup.isEnabled = true
    }
    func disable(){
        signup.isEnabled = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.signup.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHex("#333333",alpha :1)
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    return enabled ? enable() : disable()
}
@IBAction func signup(_ sender: UIButton) {


    let urlstr = "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/signup"
    let url = URL(string: urlstr)



    let param = ["email": email.text, "password":password.text,"password_confirmation":confirm_password.text,"name":name.text]


    request( url!, method: .post, parameters: param ,  encoding: JSONEncoding.default )
        .responseJSON { response in

            print(response.result.value)

            if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                //Handle the results as JSON
                let usertoken = JSON(value)
                print(usertoken)

                if let token = usertoken["token"].string {
                } else {


                    print("error")
                }

            }
    }
}
```

It only prints nil when I run it in my iPhone but in simulator it works fine

Comment: Is your phone connected to a network? Do you have an internet connection on your device?

Comment: yes, same network as my mac @Brett

Comment: Well no way to tell without some code. Why don't you try setting a breakpoint where your data is being returned?

Comment: @Brett I did and it skips  let usertoken = JSON(value) in this following code



`request( url!, method: .post, parameters: param ,  encoding: JSONEncoding.default )
            .responseJSON { response in
                
                print(response.result.value)
                
                if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
                    //Handle the results as JSON`

Comment: @Brett just added my code in my question. Please look at it

Comment: `localhost` is going to have a different meaning for your simulator and for your device, only one of which is actually running your server.